# I was promised that I would keep my seniority if I joined this company

Tags: failure, employment-agreement

In August of 2012 I was approached by the plant manager to join his company.  Part of his offer was that I would retain my seniority if I left my employer of eight years.  In September of 2013 I did.   In December of 2014 I was told that I would have it in February of 2015.

It is June 2015 and after repeated acknowledgements of saying that to me I still have not gotten it.  Do I have any legal recourse or am I, sadly out of luck since it was not in writing?

Comment: If it's not in writing, it didn't happen.

Comment: What does keeping your seniority mean? Does it give you more money, more vacation, a better parking space?

Comment: So he promised you to keep seniority after switching company and you were not given it once you did.. Would have been sufficient signal to have some alarm bells go off..

Comment: I always thought 'seniority' referred to the amount of time you're at a specific company. If you change companies, I don't see how you could keep that.

Comment: @Brandin some enterprises offer benefits to senior employees. The OP was told that, when joining the new company, they would compute the seniority at the previous company to get the benefits due to seniority in the new company

Comment: @SJuan76 In that context the word "senior" refers to a word in your title (e.g. "Senior Programmer" or something). But this 'senior' is not the same as 'seniority'. Like, let's say there's a 'senior developer' who has been in the company 6 months. Even though you've got 'senior' in your title, you still haven't got as much 'seniority' compared to the graphic designer who has been in the team for 2 years already.

Comment: @Brandin Some companies, when taking on people who have worked n years at another company, agree that they will treat that person as having worked n years at that company. I think that's what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Brandin Usually this applies to things like amount of leave they can take or eligibility for certain other benefits, it has nothing to do with job responsibilites or titles.

Answer (score 4):

If you have no written evidence of the agreement, then you probably have little chance of actually getting it.  If you have repeatedly asked and it hasn't happened, you can:

1. Ask about it *formally* and get it in writing; or
2. Accept that it will never happen and leave.

If you have it in writing at least it gives you some bounds on it and if you really feel the urge could take legal action.  But honestly, if you keep asking and it keeps being offered but it isn't being actioned, then I would suggest that you will be having the same fight again over pay increases or any other issue in future and may well be worth looking at other options.